# Remove 'server' and 'via' headers from heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

When I'm sending a request to my local server here are my response headers:

```
Connection → close
Content-Length → 7
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 27 Aug 2015 11:40:19 GMT
```

After deploying to heroku, the same code results in those headers:

```
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 7
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 27 Aug 2015 11:41:34 GMT
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3alz-zheycqsruc40pukndy8; path=/
Server → Cowboy
Via → 1.1 vegur
```

Here is my code:

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();

app.disable('etag');
app.disable('x-powered-by');

var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
router.route('/cool').post(function (req, res) {
    res.removeHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
    res.removeHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    res.removeHeader('server');
    res.removeHeader('set-cookie');
    res.removeHeader('via');
    res.set('Connection', 'close');
    return res.json({"t": 5});
});
```

How can I get rid of the `server`, `via`, `set-cookie` headers? and why `Connection` becomes `keep-alive` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened a support ticket in Heroku for that, and they responded it is not possible.

> Dan,
>
> Unfortunately, there is no way to remove those headers on a
>   per-application basis.
>
> Cheers, Damien

Here is the conversation:
[image: Heroku Ticket]

Comment: Is true in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Heroku adds those headers *after* your code runs, so there might not be a lot you can do to remove it. The response is probably on its way out the door as the extra headers are added.

You could experiment and try setting your own values for those two headers, and see if Heroku will be polite enough to not override them. But that's not much help if your goal is to have the headers not be present at all.

Comment: Tried, they are overriding.. :(

Comment: How rude! Sounds like your option are: 1) Get off Heroku, or 2) Live with it! I'm currently in the process of moving to my own AWS resources, in order to give myself more control over this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna move to AWS

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you that there is no way we can remove those response headers, but you can set the value to null if you do not wish to expose them.