# How to prevent Wappalyzer to detect heroku app?

Tags: apache, heroku

Look like wappalyzer able to detect the heroku apps by checking the `via` header :

https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/7b54cb8487350a5d5ea95d02414f83ce3cd06cd1/src/technologies/h.json#L341-L357

I'm using `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2` so how can i customize apache config to not expose that above header in an heroku app?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to obscure this? Anyway, it's unlikely that you can change this via Apache. It's probably added in as part of the overall response process _after_ your application does its thing.

Comment: Ok i dont think their gonna give us a chance to delete that header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248517/remove-server-and-via-headers-from-heroku 

i just dont wanna people see i'm using heroku , thats all

Comment: I agree, it's unlikely. But I also don't see any reason to. "I just don't want people to see" isn't a great argument.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].